# Sequence of closed intervals and the Completeness Axiom

Tags: real-analysis

(Completeness Axiom): If $I_1, I_2, I_3,\dots$ is a sequence of closed intervals such that for each positive integer $n$, $I_{n+1}$ is a subset of $I_{n}$ , then there is a point $p$ such that if $n $is any positive integer, then $p$ is in $I_n$. In other words, there is a point $p$ which is in all the closed intervals of the sequence $I_1, I_2, I_3, \dots$.

Proof:

Let $I_1, I_2, I_3, \dots$ be a sequence of closed intervals such that for each positive integer $n$, $I_{n+1} $ is a subset of $I_n$

(Our class' definition of the Completeness Axiom: If $M$ is a point set and there is a point to the right of every point of $M$, then there is either a right-most point of $M$ or a first point to the right of $M$. Similarly, if there is a point to the left of every point of $M$, then there is either a left-most point of $M$ or a first point to the left of $M$).

Let $M$ be the set $I_n$

Then by the Completeness Axiom, there is either a right-most point of a first point to the right.

Here is where I am confused, how would this help me solve this problem? I'm not sure where to go from here. I appreciate any help given. I apologize for how terrible this post is. I am new to this website.

Comment: Your class definition of completeness is very vague. A more proper / unambiguous way to express this is as follows: *Any non-empty subset of the set of real numbers which is bounded above has a least upper bound*.

Comment: By the way your approach does not help because each $I_{n} $ is a closed interval and hence has a rightmost point namely its right hand end point. Instead consider the set $M$ of all the left end points of these intervals $I_{n} $. This $M$ is bounded above (why?) and hence has a least upper bound say $a$. Similarly deal with the set of right end points of $I_{n} $.

Comment: It is bounded above means there is a point, say a, such that a is greater than or equal to m for every m in M. Right? How would showing this help show that p is in In?

Comment: Yes your interpretation of "bounded above" is correct. The set of all left end points has least upper bound $a$ and similarly the set of all right end points has a greatest lower bound $b$. Prove that $a\leq b$ and that the closed interval $[a, b] $ is a subset of all $I_n$. Any point of interval $[a, b] $ will work as desired point $p$.